# Editing a row of data table by directing to different page(pop up)

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2

I have a list of employee objects in bean class of `employee` bean class displayed in datatable ,and want to edit a particular row from the datatable in a pop up as described below

A `datagrid` with all the `employee` details, each row has `edit` button.On clicking the `edit` button the new pop-up should be displayed with the existing information of particular clicked employee and after editing, the changes must be reflected for that particular object in the list as well in datatable.

I am struggling for it but found no solution to pass object to edit in the pop up.

Comment: Shoe us your code, don't expect we will build whole solution. You should show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use primefaces inplace module to do the job (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inplace.jsf).

Comment: @Spontifixus thanks...But i m new to JSF technology can i get a demo project or code built for such applicvation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too ;) All you need to do is to create ManagedBean which will be responsible for your data. For example lets say that you have got Employee table in your database. First of all you should create entity named, for example, Employee. Next you need to create ManagedBean which will be responsible for that entity. The last step you need to do is to create view.

Employee.java (just create this file using Netbeans/Eclipse)

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {    
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String position;

    // getters and setters
}
```

EmployeeBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {

    private Employee employee;

    public void EmployeeBean() {}

    // getter and setter for Employee

    public String save() {
        // save employee data here
    }       
}
```

employee.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <!-- do it in loop -->
    <p:inplace editor="true">  
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeBean.employee.name}" required="true" label="text"/>  
    </p:inplace>
    <p:inplace editor="true">  
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeBean.employee.surname}" required="true" label="text"/>  
    </p:inplace>
    <h:commandButton action="#{employeeBean.save}" />
</h:form>
```

Using `<inplace/>` your data will be changed in ajax event so ManagedBean should (I think so but I can be wrong) SessionScoped. If not your bean will loose state.

Comment: I m still not able to make it as i have to use pop-up.My old values are not getting reflected on the pop up page for editing which i want.Might be i m not able to select the particular row to be updated by setpropertyactionlistener.

Comment: Can you paste some code? I think that it doesn't matter that you want to do it in dialog.

You can use primefaces dialog module to show this in dialog http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogHome.jsf

Comment: I am restricted to use richfaces

Comment: I don't know how to help you because I don't know how your code looks like. As I wrote before you should create ManagedBean `SessionScoped` and thats it. I've found [`inplace` module for richfaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_inplaceInput.html) so your data will be edited using ajax `in real time`. At the end you need to call some `save` method. Thats all.

Comment: Does setpropertyactionlistner works well only with string because my setter function is called if a string is used as target value but when i want an object of the class to be set it doesnt work.

<f:setPropertyActionListener immediate="true"  value="#{car}"  target="#{vcars.selectedCAR}" />

I wnat to get which row of car is seleted by the user for edit purpose from data table and reflect that contents on the pop-up page

Comment: As far as I know `setpropertyactionlistener` works well with `beans` too. I dont' really know why do you want to copy value from one bean to the other? As I can see you want to clone this object. Why?